3³+4³+5³=6³ Puzzle
A classic puzzle asks us to break a 6x6x6 cube into the smallest number of pieces which can be reassembled into 3 physically separate cubes of sizes 3, 4, & 5.
3³+4³+5³ =27+64+125 =216 =6³
An 8-piece solution is thought to be minimal, because if any single fragment contains 2-or-more of the size-6 cube's corners, then it would be 6 units long in at least one direction, & therefore too large to fit inside any smaller cube. Thus each fragment must possess exactly one of the original cube's 8 corners.
I don't recall any version of this challenge which requires that all cuts must be parallel to the original sides of the cube, but every solution that I've seen so far has been making their slices between the unit cubes, rather than through them. If there's any other method of solving this, I can't imagine how it might improve on existing solutions...
...but if anyone can prove me wrong, they are welcome to do so.
One such solution uses an intact cube of size-3 as one of the 8 fragments, while 2 other fragments assemble into the size-4 cube, & the remaining 5 fragments build the size-5 cube.
A physically different solution allows the size-4 cube to remain intact, leaving 2 fragments to make the size-3 cube, & the remaining 5 fragments to build the size-5 cube.
Is there an 8-part solution that allows the size-5 cube to remain intact?
If not, then how do we establish an impossibility proof?

As a side note, what if we remove the requirement that the 3 smaller cubes must be physically separate? If we imagine stacking the size-4 cube above the size-5 cube, then placing the size-3 cube on top, then we have defined a single 12-unit-tall 'tower' structure, containing the 3 smaller cubes, which are no longer physically separate from each other. An 8-piece solution is obviously possible, but can we build this from 7 fragments or less...?
...& if so, how much less?

Additional information at:
www.recmath.org/PolyCur/c3456/index.html
www.ericharshbarger.org/lego/puzzles.html#cubic_dissection

I think you should separate the last paragraph into a new question.  We prefer only one question per post so answers are clear what they apply to.

Thanks for the puzzle and welcome to the site!

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

@Ross Millikan:  Normally I'd agree, but based on previous experience, I believe the previous paragraphs are needed to provide sufficient clarity.

The main question asks about 8 fragments. The last question asks about 7 fragments, when you already proposed the minimum to be 8. Although the first part leads on, it's a different question. And it's unclear what you mean by "remove the requirement that the 3 smaller cubes must be physically separate".

I think the "side note" means: suppose you take 3x3x3, 4x4x4, and 5x5x5 cubes and glue them together somehow; can you make such a structure that can be decomposed into 7 pieces that reassemble to make a 6x6x6 cube?

@DMC_Run In your question you mention two 8-piece decompositions.  I would love to see them.

Is it a requirement for this puzzle that all the pieces are polycubes? (The 8-piece minimum proof appears to assume this, and the solutions posted so far only use polycubes, but it is far from obvious to me that no simpler solutions exist that makes use of non-orthogonal cuts.)

@fljx:__I've seen several versions of this puzzle challenge (the earliest being in an article by Martin Gardner, in "Scientific American"), & I don't recall that it was ever required for the solution(s) to use polycubes exclusively. If there's any non-polycube version of a solution, I'd be curious to see it. I can't currently imagine how any of the solutions that I've seen so far might be improved upon.

Main question:

 
Exploded view

Secondary question:

 
Exploded view


... I'm impressed!  I've been banging my head against this particular "brick wall" for more than 2 years!   BRAVO!

@Will Octagon Gibson: Eric Harshbarger has a site with a METRIC-TON of puzzles to explore! In his LEGO category, look for the entry "Cube Dissection" ... His 8pc. solution keeps the size-3 cube intact, & as a bonus, one of the 5 fragments that build the size-5 cube is itself a size-2 cube! ..... I've lost the link to the site containing the "intact size-4 cube" solution, but if you ask Col. George Sicherman, he should be able to help, as he pointed out the site to me originally.

My own efforts were focused on treating the bottom 6 layers of this sculpture as a single massive fragment, & trying to minimize the parts needed from the remainder. Do you have any sense of whether your 7-fragment solution represents the minimum solution?

@DMC_Run See updated images.

How did you find these? Pen-and-paper? Some suitable collection of wooden or lego bricks? Brute forcing on a computer?

@quarague I created and manipulated various blocks in a 3D CAD virtual environment, Tinkercad

Nice, so essentially a virtual version of a suitable collection of wooden bricks :-)

@DMC_Run This is a public forum, the images are already shared with the world at large. If Eric wishes to include them on his website, he may do so with any attribution he feels is appropriate.

@DMC_Run You should mark this as the answer if it solved the problem.

@matt_rule: Please forgive my ignorance, but where do I go, to mark this puzzle as solved?

@DMC_Run To the left of the answer, just below the vote up/vote down buttons, there should be a grey tick mark you can press.

@matt_rule: Thank You ... I had no idea what the tick-msrk was for! After a bit of experimenting, I see that only one tick-mark is allowed to be marked at the same time, which is also good to know.

An alternative 6-piece answer to the second question, which has the largest possible first and second piece:

 First divide the 6-cube as follows. The white piece is a 5x5x5 cube plus a layer of 4x4, and all colored unit cubes are visible.


 Then assemble the colored pieces into the 4x4x3 + 3x3x3 portion as follows. The colors of the piece(s) added in each image are green, blue, purple, and then red and yellow.

